# TCP Socket (Server) design

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp

I have a need to program a server app that accepts TCP datagrams from different systems in a given environment.  These messages can be of a finite list of message types; for example New Inventory (new item record), Inventory Location Change (inventory is now at location X), Transfer Request (please move inventory ID XYZ to Location Y from Location X) as few examples.

My question is, is it a good idea to setup a socket (port number) per inbound message type so that I can avoid having to have some type of identifier in the datagram to state what type of message it is, therefore letting me know the format of the message so that I can process it?

I am writing the Sever in .NET but the senders of the TCP messages are existing, non-.NET systems.  My plan is to setup an Asynchronous Server that saves the messages into an MSMQ for further processing. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That would certainly be a very *unusual* way to do it - and it will require more socket overhead assuming most clients require to send more than one type of message. I wouldn't do it that way

Comment: Put it this way: suppose you had to change a route for your UDP packets on a router.  How long would you like to interact with your router's arcane and indeipherable command interface?  One port is more than enough..

Comment: @Martin eugh - a firewall change every time you add a message: my sysadmins would demand payment in blood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application that I wrote communicates with multiple devices, only one of which is a PC Server, the rest are PLC’s used in manufacturing. The ports are opened and closed at each send/receive.  What I ended up doing was using a common port to receive the different TCP messages coming from the PC Server and the default send port (selected by the .NET Framework) when I send three different TCP messages to the PC Server.  In regards to the PLC’s, due to their design, I needed to use a dedicated port (that remained open) to receive their TCP messages (one dedicated port per message type [three different ones]) and one dedicated port to send each message type as the PLC’s is looking to bind to a fixed port number (again, each port had to remain open).

Thank you all for your help. This was my first TCP application and, looking back, it was quite involved (next time I’ll start with a hello world app!). I now have a 120 ton rail crane moving 30 ton roles of steal (that are 1,500 degrees) from a hot mill into a cooling yard.  Communication between all the devices, my SQL Server and a VB Windows Service are working just fine (and they say VB is a second rate language!).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a existing system you need to figure out what its [message protocol](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37496/TCP-IP-Protocol-Design-Message-Framing) is and figure out how to interpret it and follow whatever the existing system uses. Any program working with sockets has some form of "Rules" to what the messages will be, you need to find out what those rules are and have your server software follow those rules.

If your server software needs to communicate with multiple types of systems then use a different port per system type but you can't use a different port per message type per system type because that would require telling the existing system to change its "message protocol" to fit your new design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is a big help to have others fact check my thinking.  I have never had to program socket layer communication before, I usually I work way above this type of communication and your (an Marc and Martin's) perspective on it is very helpful.  I am learning that I have to figure out how to frame the message... good times. I wish I could just stick with SQL Server development!  What I need to figure out how best to get these messages so that I can process them (that’s the code I am use to writing).

Comment: If you are programming new stuff, not trying to work with existing stuff, I would recommend avoiding sockets entirely and go with a library that gives you a layer of abstraction and handles all of the message framing and whatnot for you. The [WCF library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) built in to .NET is good and there are lot of 3rd party libraries out there too.